# Javascript: find word in a div and display everything after that word?

Tags: javascript

This is a difficult to explain so please bear with me.

I need to find a word in a div and then display up to 5 other words after that word in another div.

I can find the word using javascript and it works fine but I don't know how to display the words after it in another div!

This is my current code:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
if (document.getElementById('map-directions').innerHTML.indexOf("about") != -1) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById('map-directions').innerHTML;
}
}
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<div style="height:100px; overflow:hidden;" id="map-directions">This will take sometimes, maybe about 2 hours</div>
```

so what the code above does is that it will find the word `about` in the div `map-directions` and it will display everything in the div called `demo`.

is there any way to just find the word about and display the 5 or 4 words after the word `about`?

I hope i have not confused you guys.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: words or characters?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `substring()`:

```
var index = document.getElementById('map-directions').innerHTML.indexOf("about");
var length = document.getElementById('map-directions').innerHTML.length;
if (index != -1) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById('map-directions').innerHTML.substring(index, length);
}
```

Comment: sorry but This does what my own code does! I need to limit the words/characters after about!

Comment: No it doesn't, this will display "about 2 hours" instead of "This will take sometimes, maybe about 2 hours"

Comment: Yes, correct but what I was trying to was to limit the words after about and not before it! I can already find the word about using my code so whatever before it sis not really important... thats why i said I need to limit the words after about to 5-6 words.